# Rotate element with CSS3 on demand

Tags: jquery, class, css, animation, keyframe

I defined this keyframe:

```
@-moz-keyframes rotate{
    0%{
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);   
    }
    100%{
        -moz-transform: rotate(359deg);
    }
}
```

And applied to a classname:

```
.rotate{
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-name: rotate;
}
```

And Add the class to the element on demand:

```
$('a').click(function(){ $(this).addClass('rotate'); });   /* and the class is applied */
```

But the item won't rotate; What am I doing wrong?

Please note: I am only testing in firefox, that's why I'm only using the -moz- vendor prefix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a duration:

```
.rotate{
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-animation-name: rotate;
  -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
}
```

The duration defines how long each rotation takes. If you don't set one, [the default is zero](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-duration).

Comment: but i want it infinite... where do you suggest i place it? I tried in the .rotate class and it didn't change anything

Comment: I just realised that it was working! but the child is not rotating... any idea why the childs won't rotate?

Answer (score -2):

Here is working example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div
{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:red;
animation:myfirst 1s infinite;
-webkit-animation:myfirst 1s infinite; /* Safari and Chrome */
}

@keyframes myfirst
{
from {background:red;transform:rotate(0deg);}
to {background:yellow;transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes myfirst /* Safari and Chrome */
{
from {background:red;-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);}
to {background:yellow;-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p><b>Note:</b> This example does not work in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Attribution: source comes from http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp .

Comment: It doesn't use the OP's code at all. You just copied an example from elsewhere with no commentary.

Comment: thanks for your time, but next time you shouldn't copy paste some code but let the OP know what's hes doing wrong (in the actual question code) ;)   (by the way, thanks for your downvote)